# jQuery add an element inside another one with text in it

Tags: jquery, text, append

I'm looking to add some content inside an existing div.

I'm getting the amount of images contained in another div with the following line

```
var n = $("div#content img").length;
```

I've got that element I'm trying to insert content into

```
<div id="imgCount"></div>
```

I do know that I can insert the value of my `n` var into it by doing this

```
$("#imgCount").text(n);
```

I do know as well that I can insert HTML into it by doing the following

```
$('#imgCount').append('<a href="#">sometext</a>');
```

but I'd like to combine both of them to get the following result :

```
<div id="imgCount"> <a href="#"> n </a> </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#imgCount').append('<a href="#">'+n+'</a>');
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is a very very basic one. You should get started with Javascript basics soon

```
$('#imgCount').append('<a href="#">' + n + '</a>');
```

Comment: weird that's what i did in the first place but didnt work out. now it does.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
$('#imgCount').append('<a href="#">' + n + '</a>');
```